# I have a problem with making an Instagram-like bot with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, bots

I have a problem with making an Instagram-like bot with Selenium.
I am trying to write code that passes a picture if liked, but it is not working.
Here is my code:

```
    def Like_photoTags_and_commnet(self,hashtag,comment):

    driver=self.driver
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
    time.sleep(2)

    pic_hrefs = []
    for i in range(1,3):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)
    #searching for pictures link
        hrefs_in_view = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        # finding relevant hrefs
        hrefs_in_view = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs_in_view
                         if '.com/p/' in elem.get_attribute('href')]
        # building list of unique photos
        [pic_hrefs.append(href) for href in hrefs_in_view if href not in pic_hrefs]
        print("Check: pic href length " + str(len(pic_hrefs)))

        for pics in pic_hrefs:
            driver.get(pics)
            #if picture liked then continue
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='UnLike']"):
                continue
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='Like']").click()

            if comment in driver.page_source:
                continue
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click()
                for letter in comment:
                    driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").send_keys(letter)
                    time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                time.sleep(5)
```

I'm geting this error in console.
the problem is in line 52.you guys have any suggestion?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/behro/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py", line 52, in Like_photoTags_and_commnet
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='UnLike']"):
  File "C:\Users\behro\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\behro\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\behro\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\behro\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button/span[@aria-label='UnLike']"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample work to find the followers of hashtags is giver here. For the complete automation, just go foe my github page. That is for information and study purpose only so if there is any problem regarding "class not found" or " element not found", just change inspect the element and change the tag/class name.It happend because they keep changing the path and names.

https://www.github.com/deshwalmahesh

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import random
from random import randint
import os


def update_file():
    with open('hashtags.txt') as f:
        main_list=f.read().splitlines()

    return(main_list)

def format(num):
    x=num.replace(',','')
    num=int(x)
    if num>999 and num<=999999:
        x=num%1000
        y=num//1000
        return(str(y)+'.'+str(x)[0]+'K')
    elif num>999999:
        x=num%1000000
        y=num//1000000
        return (str(y) + '.' + str(x)[0] + ' M')
    else: return (num)



br=webdriver.Chrome()
br.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
time.sleep(5)
br.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('username')
br.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('password',Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)

main_list=update_file()
count=0
while True:
    try:
        br.get('https://www.instagram.com')
        time.sleep(3)
        if "Turn on" in br.page_source:
            x=br.find_element_by_class_name('mt3GC')
            a=x.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
            a[1].click()
            time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(count,len(main_list)):
            tag=(str(main_list[i]))
            a=tag.strip()
            tag=a.lower()
            a=tag.replace(' ','')
            tag=a.replace('\n','')
            a=tag.replace('\t','')
            br.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+a)
            print(a)
            time.sleep(7)
            find=br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='g47SY ']")
            time.sleep(2)
            posts=find[0].text
            post=format(posts)
            print(post)
            with open('posts.txt', 'a') as f:
                x = str(post)
                f.write('%s\n' % x)

            with open('tags.txt', 'a') as f:
                x = '#'+a
                f.write('%s\n' % x)     

        time.sleep(3)

        count+=1

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to find an element that is not there! hence the error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element

So you can use `try` and `except`.

```
for pics in pic_hrefs:
    driver.get(pics)
    #if picture liked then continue
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='UnLike']"):
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[@aria-label='Like']").click()
```

Don't forget to import it: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Now about your `sleep`'s you should use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) instead.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much it works. but after this ,driver will like comments because comment like button and post like button have the same elements .do you have any suggestion for skipping post that liked before?